# Grails Logging - Exclude One Class

Tags: grails, logging, log4j

I have a project consisting of hundreds of various classes.  One of these extends a class located in a JAR library and produces tons of log info.  I would like to exclude this one class from producing all this logging information.

Here's my config.groovy logging section:

```
trace('grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.DebugFilter',
      'grails.app.conf.com.myrootpackage',
      'grails.app.controllers.com.myrootpackage',
      'grails.app.domain.com.myrootpackage',
      'grails.app.filters.com.myrootpackage',
      'grails.app.services.com.myrootpackage',
      'grails.app.taglib.com.myrootpackage',
      'com.myrootpackage')
```

Since all of my classes are located in the com.myrootpackage package or sub packages of that, I'm not sure how to exclude the one class.  As far as I can tell, the logging setup in config.groovy only allows specifying the beginning of class names so I would have to specify by name all other classes and omit the one I want to omit, or move the one I want to omit to a separate root package.  Both of these seem silly to have to do to just omit one class from producing log output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As far as I can tell, the logging setup in config.groovy only allows specifying the beginning of class names

No, you can use the full class name to configure an individual class, so the following should work

```
trace('grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.DebugFilter',
      'grails.app.conf.com.myrootpackage',
      'grails.app.controllers.com.myrootpackage',
      'grails.app.domain.com.myrootpackage',
      'grails.app.filters.com.myrootpackage',
      'grails.app.services.com.myrootpackage',
      'grails.app.taglib.com.myrootpackage',
      'com.myrootpackage')

error 'com.myrootpackage.ExcludeMe'
```

I've assumed

- `com.myrootpackage.ExcludeMe` is the fully-qualified name of the class in question
- this class should log at the error level instead of trace